# Rendering function/Component without a call from render function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a component, and I want to make it easy to use. I don't wanna call my component like the following way,

`<myComponent {...someProps} />`

I'm looking for a specific way, I'm still new in React I don't know exactly the name and how can I do it.
is there any way to call my component as a hook or something similar, let's take this component as an example?

```
export const useComponent = (props) => {  
  const [show, setShow] = useState('show');
  
  const onShow = (value) => { setShow(value); }

  return (
    // Content
    <div className={show}>
      Component 
      <button onClick={onShow(hide)}>Hide</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I need to show what inside content using a function, like that

```
const onShow = useComponent();

//if I want to show it I will call onShow function
<button onClick={onShow('show')}>Show Component</button>
```

What I want basically is when I clicked on the 'Show Component' button I want to show the useComponent, without calling it inside HTML like .
it's like it gonna be easy for to everyone use my component.

Comment: Sounds like what you're looking for is how to [conditionally render a component](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator).

Comment: No. For multiple reasons. 1 - You should **never** call a component function yourself. This leaves React out of the process entirely, and it can no longer manage state or lifecycle (your hooks will throw errors). 2 - `onClick` doesn't return anything. Conceptually it makes no sense for it to return anything. If it did, where would it render the JSX? Inside the button? Above it? Below?

Comment: @BrianThompson maybe there is a clean way to do that

Comment: move your `show` and `setShow` to the component that has the `button`. on click of the `button` set the `show` and conditionally render the `Component` based on the state `show`

Comment: I'm looking for a way to show it using a function inside Component. @Prasanna

Comment: sorry. i'm not getting the question then. the function will return a component. but calling a function on `onClick` isn't clear here. where do you want the return value to be rendered? `onClick` can't return a component that can be rendered

Comment: yes, that's my question how can I do that, maybe I need to change something on my component.
that's what I want 

`const openComponent = myCustomComponent({ ..someProps})
<Button label=“Open” type=“tertiary” onClick={openComponent } />
`@Prasanna

Comment: something similar to https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-useimperativehandle-forked-fcfht. @Prasanna

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a wrapper component using the  [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).
This is, in my opinion, one of the advanced features of React. Super useful of course, but if you are a beginner, try creating just a component :)
Anyway, you missed in your description, what the custom hook should do. If you need a more precise answer, try giving some more info :)

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useContext} from 'react';

export const ComponentContext = createContext(null);

/**
 * Don't forget to describe your provider
 * @param {object} args react args
 * @param {JSX.Element | Array<JSX.Element>} args.children children to show
 */
export const ComponentProvider = ({ children }) => {


  const [show, setShow] = useState('show');
  
  const onShow = (value) => { setShow(value); }

  return (
    <ComponentContext.Provider
      value={{ show, onShow }}
      children={children}
    />
  );
};

/**
 * Hook used to get the props you defined
 * @returns {{show:boolean,onShow:function}}
 */
export const useComponent = () => {
  const res = useContext(UserContext);
  return res;
};
```

You can then use your component in the wrapper or App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { ComponentProvider } from './custom-hooks/ComponentProvider';
function App() {
  return (
    <ComponentProvider>
      <YourComponent />
    </ComponentProvider >
  );
}
```

and finally, use the functions you need in the element

```
import { useComponent } from './custom-hooks/ComponentProvider';

...

const { onShow } = useComponent();

return (
   <button onClick={()=>onShow('show')}>Show Component</button>
);
```

Comment: is everything correct? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-useimperativehandle-forked-g8t74

Comment: Not even close. You missed the part of the wrapper or App.jsx. :D
You have to define the Context of the component in order to use "useComponent"

Comment: is there any way to avoid defining anything inside the HTML part,

Comment: On click has to be defined in the html. For more complex stuff, you could use useRef, but again, this is advanced react. Make sure to understand the simple things first :)

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:**

I think you're looking for HOC. You can create Higher Order Component using useComponent and serve/provide wherever you need it by following example.

```
const withComponent = (WrappedComponent) => {
  const WithComponent = (props) => {
    function useComponent(status, setStatus) {
      return (
        <div>
          {status == "show" && <div>
            <p>Inner Contents</p>
            <button onClick={() => setStatus("hide")}>Hide Inner Contents</button>
          </div>}
          
        </div>
      );
    }
    return <WrappedComponent {...props} useCompoent={useComponent} />;
  };

  return WithComponent;
};

const App = (props) => {
  const { useCompoent } = props;

  const [status, setStatus] = useState("hide");

  const getUseComponent = useCompoent(status, setStatus);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {getUseComponent}
      <button onClick={() => setStatus("show")}>
        Show Component
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withComponent(App);
```

You can move `withComponent` into separate file as well.

Comment: it's not clear how can I use HOC in my case

Comment: You can add button instead of P tag inside the `useComponent` function and trigger to hide/show function to display html (for ex. modal).

Comment: You can't return html & events when you call as a function. it will not render any html. So you need HOC to call as a function(in your desired way - without rendering the component as <myComponent/>).

Comment: I made a sandbox to show/hide inner function based on click https://codesandbox.io/s/react-managing-function-modal-externally-zpqyv Hope it will be useful

Comment: in your solution I need to call `getUseComponent` inside HTML.

Comment: I doubt, whether there is any method to display html without render anything (in this case  `getUseComponent `) You can use Portal instead of HOC, but still it need to be called from render function.